# C: Converting Julian Dates into Gregorian

Tags: c, matrix, converters

This is my current Code, and the output is as follows:

Please Enter a Julian Day number greater than 2299160

2299161

15 10 1582

However this does not provide me the exact time if for example there were decimals 2299161.1 etc.

How would this be implemented in C? I already know the math :

```
0.1 days = 0.1 * 24 hours   = 2 hours    (remainder 0.4 hours),
       0.4 * 60 minutes = 24 minutes (remainder 0.0 seconds)
       0.0 * 60 seconds = 0 seconds
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
   double jdn; /* you will need to store the user's input here... */
   long lc, kc, nc, ic, jc;
   int day, month, year;
   printf("Please Enter a Julian Day number greater than 2299160 \n");
   scanf("%lf",&jdn);


 if( jdn > 2299160 ){
   printf("%d\n",jdn);
   lc = jdn + 68569;
   nc = ((4 * lc) / 146097);
   lc = lc - ((146097 * nc + 3) / 4);
   ic = ((4000 * (lc + 1)) / 1461001);
   lc = lc - ((1461 * ic) / 4) + 31;
   jc = ((80 * lc) / 2447);
   day = lc - ((2447 * jc) / 80);
   lc = (jc / 11);
   month = jc + 2 - 12 * lc;
   year = 100 * (nc - 49) + ic + lc;

   printf("%d %d %d\n", day, month, year);
  }
  else {
  printf("Invalid number");
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend a combination of `floor()` as used by @Paul R, integer `%` and `*` as used by @user3386109 and using `round()`.

```
#include <math.h>

double frac_d = jdn - floor(jdn);  // @Paul R

#define SecPerDay (24L*60*60)
long  frac_l = (long) round(frac_d * SecPerDay);

int sec = frac_l % 60;  // @user3386109
frac_l /= 60;
int min = frac_l % 60;
frac_l /= 60;
int hrs = total;
```

Using `floor()` vs. `modf()` is important should negative Julian date times occur.

Rounding a double before assigning to an integer insures values like 12.99999999 take on the integer value 13 rather than 12.

For portability reasons, prefer `long` over `int` for values that may exceed 32767.

---

[edit]

My concern on the below statement was not proven out.  Either approach of calculating `h,m,s` would come up equally well with *consistent* values. Still prefer the integer approach as less code and easier to control rounding.

"Calculating h,m,s, from one integer insures consistent values from the fraction." (not valid)

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the fractional part like this:

```
#include <math.h>

double jdn_frac = jdn - floor(jdn);
```

and then it's quite simple to convert this to h:m:s:

```
int h = (int)(jdn_frac * 24.0);
int m = (int)((jdn_frac * 24.0 - h) * 60.0);
int s = (int)(((jdn_frac * 24.0 - h) * 60.0 - m) * 60.0);
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aec550afdd8d4970)

Comment: Error when Compiling...Undefined reference to 'floor'

Comment: I don't know what compiler you're using, but for gcc you may need to add `-lm` to the command line.

Comment: i am using Gcc.. so gcc <name>.c -lm ?

Comment: Yes, or better yet `gcc -Wall -lm foo.c`

Answer (score 0):

Start by breaking the input number into integer and fractional parts

```
double n, f;
f = modf( jdn, &n );
```

That will give you 0.1 in `f` and 2299161 in `n`.

Then convert the fractional part to seconds:

```
0.1 days = 0.1 * 24 hours = 0.1 * 24 * 3600 seconds

int total = f * 24 * 3600;
```

Then you can break it down using modulo and division

```
seconds = total % 60;
total /= 60;
minutes = total % 60;
total /= 60;
hours = total;
```

Comment: Can i edit instead of f = modf(2299161.1, &n); use 

f = modf(jdn, &n);

Comment: Yes, the first argument to `modf` is the number that you want to break into integer and fractional parts.  So `f=modf(jdn, &n);` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the seconds, minutes and hours given in the above two posts will be mean solar time units. Currently, the mean solar day is 86400.002 s long (http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/leapsec.html). If you need precision on the order of one part in 40 million, you will need to correct for this. :-)

Comment: http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/ server not found

Comment: Try https://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/time/master-clock/leap-seconds instead. This changed in 2020.